# Textorientation in PDFlib with PHP

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I've found a strange behaviour in pdflib while trying to get a text
rotated in a table, in order to save page space.

The pdflib documentation states, that:

```
fittextflow={rotate=90}
```

Should produce the effect I want. The strang is, that my pdf creation
codes failes to run, loging:

ExceptionHandler: cell in column(s) 1 and row(s) 1: unknown option 'fittextflow'
1)pdf_add_table_cell()

I also tried:

```
fittextflow={orientate=north}
```

which neither worked out.

I'm on pdflib 7.0.1p1.

Does anyone have a hint on this one?

tia

K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a detail, but an importatant one:

```
fittextline={rotate=90}
```

Works as desired.